# Get value from slider and send it in form

Tags: javascript, html, thymeleaf

I would like to use values from slider in my form.
Where should I put:

```
th:field="*{salaryMin}" and th:field="*{salaryMax}"
```

in HTML? I was trying in hidden inputs but it does not work

Code from HTML, CSS amd JS are in links becouse it is too big for snippet
[codepen.io](https://codepen.io/jackiejohnston/pen/NNrpjQ)